# How can I partially plot a Healpix map using Healpy?

Tags: python, healpy

When working with healpy, I am able to plot a Healpix map in Mollview using

```
import healpy
map = 'filename.fits'
healpy.visufunc.mollview(map)
```

or as in the tutorial

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import healpy as hp
>>> NSIDE = 32
>>> m = np.arange(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE))
>>> hp.mollview(m, title="Mollview image RING")
```

which outputs

[image]

Is there a way to display only certain regions of the map? For example, only the upper hemisphere, or only the left side?

What I have in mind is viewing only small patches of the sky to see small point sources, or something like the "half-sky" projection from LSST

[image]

Comment: You might also find the [`reproject`](https://reproject.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#documentation) package useful, which allows you to reproject HEALPix maps onto smaller regions. The documentation contains a few examples of how to do the reprojection and the plotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mask, which is a boolean map of the same size, where 1 are masked, 0 are not masked:

http://healpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#masked-map-partial-maps

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import healpy as hp
NSIDE = 32
m = hp.ma(np.arange(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE), dtype=np.double))
mask = np.zeros(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE), dtype=np.bool)
pixel_theta, pixel_phi = hp.pix2ang(NSIDE, np.arange(hp.nside2npix(NSIDE)))
mask[pixel_theta > np.pi/2] = 1
m.mask = mask
hp.mollview(m)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a precise way to know which pixels I am masking? (I think if one simply defines the mask in terms of coordinates above, that should be ok, if I know the positions of the individual pixels.)

Comment: yes, `pixel_theta, pixel_phi` are the coordinates of the pixel centers, `theta` is colatitude and `phi` is longitude.